# Using machine learning to classify text client-side in JavaScript?

Tags: machine-learning, javascript

Apologies in advance, I am completely new to the world of machine learning. But I just wanted a bit of help in areas to explore or even just a blunt answer if the following was possible.

I have a chrome extension that gets the content of a webpage and am wanting to classify this text into what topic it is - ie. math, science, geography, etc. I know there are several APIs that I could send the data of too initially but was wanting to know if this thing would be possible to do within the extension using javascript.

I made a quick and dirty demo in which I trained https://github.com/nemo/natural-synaptic with a small amount of data and exported it to JSON. I then imported this into the extension and used it to classify the text, it works okay. However, I would need more training data to classify it correctly and it also seems to have a small performance hit when loading an already small amount of trained data (4mb) so increasing this may affect performance even more.

My overall questions are - How feasible is a text classifier using javascript all client side without affecting performance too much? And is there any frameworks, resource you could suggest I look into? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe not exactly what you want but [this](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/) may help you.

Comment: @Media. Thanks, I'm just exploring the idea at the minute so every little helps.